# use the shell method to find the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the given curves about the x-axis.

Tags: calculus

Use the shell method to find the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the given curves about the $x$-axis. $x = 4y^2$, $x = -4y$, $y = 4$

How is $y=4$ used in this problem?

Comment: I believe the region being revolved consists of the region bounded on the left by $x=-4y$, on the right by $x=4y^2$, and on top by $y=4$, and possibly the region bounded by $x=-4y$ on the right and by $x=4y^2$ on the left as well.